# How do packets flow in a Fortigate HA cluster during fail-over?

Tags: switch, fortigate

How does a Fortigate unit in HA cluster prevent a switch from sending packets to the failed unit ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The new primary unit interfaces have different physical connections than the failed primary unit. Both the failed and the new primary unit interfaces are connected to the same switches, but the new primary unit interfaces are connected to different ports on these switches. To make sure that the switches send packets to the new primary unit, the new primary unit interfaces send gratuitous ARP packets to the connected switches. These gratuitous ARP packets notify the switches that the primary unit MAC and IP addresses are on different switch ports and cause the switches to send packets to the ports connected to the new primary unit. In this way, the new primary unit continues to receive packets that would otherwise have been sent to the failed primary unit.